# Save access token in Kotlin Object in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an android app with kotlin.

I load my access token from Room (android local DB) in main activity.

And with RxJava2, I get the access token throw ViewModel. And I have a Kotlin Object that I can save Token inside. The Reason I use Kotlin Object is to use the access token simply, not load token from Room every time I need it.

So, this is the code about that

```
//In Main Activity, onCreate
viewModel.token.observe(this, Observer {
    TokenObject.token = it // type of it is MyToken
})
```

Access Token Data class

```
data class MyToken(val token: String, val refreshToken: String)
```

TokenObject

```
object TokenObject {
    var token: MyToken? = null
}
```

But After Main Activity destroyed and ViewModel cleared, The value inside TokenObject still remains (I can use TokenObject.token in Second Activity)

Can it cause a memory leak?

Comment: No, it won't cause a memory leak, BUT it won't be initialized properly after process death when your application launches directly on SecondActivity and had never been on Main.

Comment: Why do you need token in the activity?

Comment: @Antonio When I send a request to a server by using retrofit2 I add token to the header. And to use the access token simply, I set TokenObjects.token and use it.

Comment: What is the need of taking it to activity and initialize it there? I used to save access token in shared preferences and attach to retrofit requests directly from repository class.

Comment: Umm...I thought using room with a kotlin object is better than using shared preferences. But now I'm confused.  Do you think using shared preferences is better than using room for saving and using token? I really don't know which is a better way. sorry for my English

Comment: In case of access token it is better to use shared preferences since it is simply a string.

Comment: @Antonio Thanks for your comment, I will try your way.